# php foreach loop with $key confusion

Tags: php, foreach

here is the result when I `var_dump($products)` : http://pastebin.com/6EuRXEnC

It has 3 items, and each item has 4 extra img which is image_1,image_2,image_3 and image_4.

how can I use foreach to retrieve them in order?

when I test like this

```
foreach($products as $product){ 
echo $product['image_1'];
}
```

it is not in order, means they are not being grouped according. My expected output is

image_1,2,3,4 will have 3 set of group which belong to item1,2 and 3 because they will be use in `<img>` in group.

Comment: Not in order, means ? what is your expected output ?

Comment: @user3856475 image_1,2,3,4 will have 3 set of group which belong to item1,2 and 3.

Comment: Is that a typo here or your original code: `echo $product[image_1'];` should be `echo $product['image_1'];`

Comment: @AxelAmthor ops, fixed it.

Comment: Please give an example for your expected output.

Comment: @AxelAmthor image_1,2,3,4 will have 3 set of group which belong to item1,2 and 3 because they will be use in <img> in group.

Comment: I can read. That's way unclear as from your pastebin image_1 is a string, image_2 is a string and I'm afraid I don't understand your "group" - there's none for me-

Comment: @AxelAmthor, imagine I want to use them in img, I don't want to mix them up. there will be 3 div representing 3 item, and within each item they will have their img which is image_1,2,3 and 4.

Comment: An **example** would be helpful, i.e. if @Ghost 's solution isn't what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a for loop inside that foreach. Like this:

```
foreach($products as $product) {
    echo '<div class="each_product">';
    // there are 4 images
    for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
        if(isset($product["image_".$i])) { // just to be safe
            echo '<img src="'.htmlspecialchars($product['image_'.$i], ENT_QUOTES).'" alt="image" />';  
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: should have an `if ( isset...` better.

Comment: @AxelAmthor yeah could add that for the safe side

Comment: @Ghost imagine I want to use them in img, I don't want to mix them up. there will be 3 div representing 3 item, and within each item they will have their img which is image_1,2,3 and 4

Comment: @Adam91 by the way do you have a `var_export($products)` that will make this easier

Comment: @Adam91 check out the revision, the design part is yours to make this is the basic idea